# Using Addthis, how can I use a custom icon and share a particular image on Pinterest?

Tags: icons, share, pinterest, addthis

I'm using `Addthis` to add share buttons to a Wordpress blog.

My custom icons work with the exception of Pinterest.

I am able to use a custom icon when I use the class `addthis_button_pinterest_share` but not when I use the class `addthis_button_pinterest_pinit`.

Inside my loop, the following results in a prompt to share the image correctly, but the icon image is overridden by the Pinterest button:

```
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" pi:pinit:media="<?= wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>" pi:pinit:description="<?= get_the_excerpt();?>">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/icons/social/pinterest.png" />
</a>
```

Meanwhile, this results in a prompt to share from a gallery of images that are on the page (not the image I specify), but the custom icon image works:

```
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share" pi:pinit:url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" pi:pinit:media="<?= wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>" pi:pinit:description="<?= get_the_excerpt();?>">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/icons/social/pinterest.png" />
</a>
```

Is there a way I can use a custom icon with `addthis_button_pinterest_pinit` or specify a particular image to share using  `addthis_button_pinterest_share`?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a particular image to share using addthis_button_pinterest_share through Open Graph protocol. Try adding this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="URL to your image" />
```

Here's also some more reference regarding addthis_button_pinterest_share http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1300322-pinterest-image-sharing

Comment: This no longer seems to work with the "share" button. Also, the page at that link appears to be gone.